# Traer nombre de usuario (username) desde el id en otra tabla

Tags: nodejs, orm, sequelize.js

Tengo dos modelos User y Blacklist, la relación es User tiene muchos Blacklist y Blacklist pertenece a User. En la tabla Blacklist guardo el id del usuario que bloquea (user_id) y el id del usuario bloqueado (user_id_blocked)

Esto lo hago para tener una lista de usuarios bloquedos por un usuario (como lo hace facebook cuando uno bloquea a otro usuario), para esto tengo un método llamado Blacklist dentro del controlador UserController en donde voy guardando los ID de los bloqueados. El problema que tengo es cuando quiero traer en una consulta el username del usuario bloqueado, no logro hacer eso y es en lo que necesito guía, el método para mostrar el username de los usuarios bloqueados se llama blackListShow.

Modelo User.js

```
const { Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

class User extends Model {
static init(sequelize) {
    super.init(
        {
            name: DataTypes.STRING,
            email: DataTypes.STRING,
            username: DataTypes.STRING,
            password: DataTypes.STRING
        },
        {
            sequelize
        }
    );
}

this.hasMany(models.Blacklist, {
        as: 'blacklist'
    });
}
};
 module.exports = User;
```

Modelo Blacklist.js

```
const { Model, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');

class Blacklist extends Model {
static init(sequelize) {
    super.init(
        {
            user_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            user_id_blocked: DataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        {
            sequelize
        }
    );
 }

 static associate(models){
    this.belongsTo(models.User, {
        foreignKey: 'user_id',
        as: "userBlacklist"
    });
 }
 }
 module.exports = Blacklist;
```

Método Blacklist (UserController) donde guardo los ids de usuarios que bloquean y los ids de usuarios bloqueados.

```
  async blackList (req, res) {
    const { userIdBlocked } = req.body;
    const userId = req.userId;

    const userFind = await User.findByPk(userIdBlocked);

    if(!userFind)
        return res.status(400).json({
            message: 'El usuario a bloquear no existe.'
        });

    if(userId === parseInt(userIdBlocked)) 
        return res.status(400).json({
            message: 'No puedes bloquearte a ti mismo.'
        });

    const userBlock = await Blacklist.findOne({
        where: { 
                [Sequelize.Op.and]: [{ user_id: userId }, { user_id_blocked: userIdBlocked }]
        }
    });

    if(userBlock) 
        return res.status(400).json({
            message: 'Este usuario ya se encuentra bloqueado por ti.'
        });

    await Blacklist.create({
        user_id: userId,
        user_id_blocked: userIdBlocked
    });

    return res.status(200).json({
        message: 'El usuario ha sido bloqueado.'
    });

},
```

Método blackListShow (dentro de UserController) es aquí dónde no sé traer el nombre de usuario en la consulta hecha al modelo BlackList quien tiene los ids de los usuarios bloqueados.

```
 async blackListShow (req, res) {

    const blackList = await Blacklist.findAll({
        where: { user_id: req.userId },
        attributes: {
             exclude: ['id', 'updatedAt'],
        }
    });
  }
```

En este método (blackListShow) en dónde el usuario conectado (req.userId) tiene que ver la lista de los usuarios (username) bloqueados por él.

Alguna idea de como solucionar esto?

Answer (score 0):

Al final traje todos los usuarios bloqueados por X usuario, luego cree un array con los IDs de los usuarios para posterior hacer una consulta al modelo User con los IDs de cada usuario de la lista y mostrar el resultado mediante un json.